# What is the relationship between Python 3 built-in types?

Tags: python

In python 3 everything is a object. I drew a diagram about relation of classes. Is this diagram correct?

[image]

the hard part is about type and object classes. how are they in relation ?
type is a object ? or object is a type ?

```
>>> x=type
>>> type(x)
<class 'type'>
>>> x=object
>>> type(x)
<class 'type'>
```

Comment: What do the arrows mean? In python, everything is an object and every object has a type. The type of the object class is type and type is an instance of object - a circular reference.

Comment: Also notice: `issubclass(bool, int) == True`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the class relations are kind of like this in Python 3:

- Every class is a **subclass** of `object`
- Every class is an **instance** of `type`

Every class is created by the `type` class or an other metaclass, which derives from `type`. Because of this every class is an instance of `type` (including `type`!) Every class will return `True` for `isinstance(cls, type)`.

In Python 3, every class is also a subclass from `object`. Every class or instance will return `True` for `isinstance(cls_or_instance, object)`

A special case is metaclasses. A metaclass derives from `type`, so every metaclass will return `True` for `issubclass(metaclass, type)` and `isinstance(metaclass, type)`

Comment: AFAIK python relies heavily on duck typing, class creation is no exception. The meta class should not be required to actually be derived from `type` it just have to have to behave accordingly.

Comment: I didn't know that. But shouldn't it still call 'type' to create a class? (with type(name, bases, dict))

Comment: No, it calls the metaclass whatever that is (with `meta(name, bases, dict)`) and whatever that returns is assigned to the class name. Then if you try to instantiate the class the class will be called (with `cls(*args, **kwds)`) and whatever that is will be the instance. Note that there is no requirement that the class will be of the type `meta` and that the instance has to be of type `cls`.

Answer (score 0):

The type object is itself an object. Note though that the inheritance model of python is not the same as in other OO-languges, much of it depends on duck typing rather than inheritance.

Note that `type(x)` returns the type of the object, that `type(object)` returns `<class 'type'>` means nothing more than the type of `object` (which is the type all objects has) is a `type` (the type all types are), `type` itself is a type so the type of it is again `type`.